# Setting up ScrollMagic plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollmagic

I am currently learning JavaScript and jQuery and would like to start using ScrollMagic plugin.

Unfortunately I am stuck on the first hurdle- I've spent hours on this, following various tutorials online, but I just cannot get the plugin to work!?

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Many thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Init ScrollMagic
  var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

  // Scene 1 - pin the second section
  var pinScene01 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: '#nav',
      triggerHook: 0,
      duration: '100%'
    })
    .setPin('#nav .nav1')
    .addTo(controller);

});
```

```css
.nav1 {
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: #090;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.div1 {
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: #F33;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.div2 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #FCC;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="div1">Div one content!</div>

  <div class="nav1" id="#nav">Nav bar div</div>

  <div class="div2">And more content...</div>

  <div class="div1">And a repeat!</div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.gsap.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.2/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your scripts are conflicting with one another. You only need to have the first jQuery script, and the first ScrollMagic script listed, you can remove the rest. Not sure if that is your main problem, but that is most definitely one of your problems :)

Comment: he's using failsafe loading of jquery, download from googleapis, if it's not reachable, use local copy ;)

Comment: I copied the code from a tutorial page where it seemed to work fine. I tried removing the rest but no luck!?

Could it have something to do with the positioning of the elements? Do elements have to have a parent with css position applied to them?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reference to the JavaScript code in your HTML file.

Include a link to it under all the other JS files and it should work.

Comment: Actually, the code above was all part of one page so the JavaScript was included in the very last script tag in the body!?

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>

<body>

<div class="div1">Div one content!</div>

<div class="nav1" id="nav">Nav bar div</div>

<div class="div2">And more content...</div>

<div class="div1">And a repeat!</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.gsap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.2/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{margin: 0; padding: 0;}    
.nav1 {height: 40px;background-color: #090;position: relative;float: left; width: 100%;}
.div1 {height:1000px;background-color: #F33;position: relative;float: left; width: 100%;}
.div2 {height: 1000px;background-color: #FCC;position: relative;float: left; width: 100%;}
</style>    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
            var pinScene01 = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
                  triggerElement: '#nav',
                  triggerHook: 0
                })
                .setPin('#nav', {pushFollowers: false})
                .addIndicators({
                    color: '#f00',
                    name: 'nav'
                })      
                .addTo(controller);

            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```